# PHP - Get All values from object without knowing properties

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm having an issue with displaying object properties.

normally you would call them using :

```
$obj["name"]
```

but what if you did not know the properties e.g "name"

for an array , you can simply call $arr[0] , $arr[1] etc...

But if i have this object (`print_r`):

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [Name] => george  [Number] => 437439742 [Email] => hds@gmail.com) 

stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [Name] => tom  [Number] => 4343554643 [Email] => fdhk@gmail.com)
```

how can i use a foreach to display all the values e.g : 1 , george , 437...

-Without knowing the name of the properties -> NOT $o["id"];

```
foreach($object as $o)
{
  echo $o[i];    // doesn't work on objects
}
```

I tried converting it to arrays , but it will be an array of the objects so i can;t get the inside info.

```
//$array = array ($object);
```

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [`get_object_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php).

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options. One is the [`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) function, and another is to cast the object to an array.

```
foreach (get_object_vars($object) as $var => $val) {
    // ...
}
```

or

```
foreach ((array) $object as $var => $val) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$array = get_object_vars($obj);
```

Comment: Please try to add more description to your answer.